# How to support multiple schedulers with spring boot quartz

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

Here's my use case:

- I have 1 DB and 1 set of tables for quartz
- I have a spring boot application X which have N nodes (VMs) and job class A, B and C
- I have another spring boot application Y which have M nodes and job class D, E and F

How should I define application.properties for each application to make sure the quartz schedule the job to the right clusters? (job A,B,C goes to N and job D,E,F goes to M)

I guess this should be required for both applications:

```
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
```

But I'm not sure which of below property make the call, or I need define both for each application:

```
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=???
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=???
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: application X and Y are sharing one schema?

Comment: yes, 1 schema. same set of quartz related tables in mysql. but for biz, they have their own DB/schemas

Comment: if you use separate schemas for each app, there is nothing special you should need to do

Comment: Hey it's been a while, but did you achieve what you were initially looking to achieve @user13042537 ? I'm in a similar situation and would like to use the same schema, in the same database, for two different springboot applications that both have their own scheduled jobs.

Edit: I'm assuming this is the answer I'm looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069594/multiple-quartz-instances-on-the-same-server-instance-and-same-jobstore